# What is the markdown syntax for .NET Core templating

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a [.NET Core template](https://github.com/cilerler/burcin/blob/master/dist/.template.config/template.json) and wondering how I can hide partial content from markdown file based on the flags set?

As you may see below I tried what I do in CS project files but it didn't work.

### README.md

```
# Steps

- createSolutionFile.ps1

<!--#if (CacheSqlServer)-->
- sql-cache.ps1
    1. create database `DistributedCache`
    2. create schema `cache`
    3. run the script
<!--#endif-->

- user-secrets.ps1

<!--#if (EntityFramework)-->
- scaffold.ps1
- migrate.ps1 
<!--#endif-->

- build.ps1

<!--#if (WindowsService)-->
- windows-service.ps1
<!--#endif-->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The templating engine by default only supports these conditional operators only in a certain list of file types, sometimes with varying syntax. You can find that list of files [in the source of the orchestrator](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/blob/8986b68/src/Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Orchestrator.RunnableProjects/SimpleConfigModel.cs#L387-L464). As of now, the list does not include Markdown files though, which is why you are not getting any functionality there.

Fortunately, there appears to be a way to configure [special custom operations](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/%22Runnable-Project%22-Templates#customoperations-optional-and-specialcustomoperations-optional) on custom file types inside the `template.json`, which allows you to define [custom operations](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/%22Runnable-Project%22-Templates#customoperationsoperations-optional) e.g. for conditional operators.

Adding something like this should work:

```js
"SpecialCustomOperations": {
  "**/*.md": {
    "operations": [
      {
        "type": "conditional",
        "configuration": {
          "if": ["---#if"],
          "else": ["---#else"],
          "elseif": ["---#elseif", "---#elif"],
          "endif": ["---#endif"],
          "trim" : "true",
          "wholeLine": "true",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It should allow you to use conditionals like this in your `.md` files:

```
# This is an example Markdown

---#if (FooBar)
Foo bar
---#elif (BarBaz)
Bar baz
---#else
Baz qux
---#endif
```

Note that I used a different syntax here as a single-line based syntax is a lot easier to configure.

Comment: @cilerler Could you please **not** edit the whole answer like that? There is a reason I used a different syntax here. Non-line-based conditionals are more complicated to set up since you need actionable conditionals and additional actions. – If you want to maintain the syntax of conditionals from the question and you figure out a *working* configuration for that, you are free to post that as a separate answer.

Comment: my bad, sorry.  I didn't realize you did it on purpose.  Thanks again...