# Add optional content in dotnet new templates in non c# files

Tags: c#, dotnet-cli

I want to modify the content of README.md based on what the developer selects when creating a c# solution from the template. How do I do it?

I know that you can define

```
"symbols": {
    "EnableContent":{
        "type": "parameter",
        "dataType":"bool",
        "defaultValue": "true"
    }
}
```

in `template.config/template.json` to enable optional content in dotnet new templates.

In c# code, you can then use the defined symbol to include some code, if `EnableContent` is set to true (using c# preprocessor directives)

```
#if (EnableContent)
        public string foo()
        {
            return "bar";
        }

#endif
```

And in .cshtml it can be used like

```
@*#if (EnableContent)
<p>foobar</p>
#endif*@
```

Is there any way to add similar decision making in non c# files like markdown files (.md)? Or does this depend on c# preprocessor directives to be available? If so, is there any workaround to use c# preprocessor directives in markdown files in the context of using templates for dotnet new.

ps. I know that in this example I could just do two different versions of README.md and then select correct one using source modifiers

```
"sources": [
    {
        "modifiers": [
            {
                "condition": "(EnableContent)",
                "exclude": [ "README1.md" ]
            },
            {
                "condition": "(!EnableContent)",
                "exclude": [ "README2.md" ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

in `template.config/template.json` but my actual need more complex than that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I eventually figure out this my self. There is a way, called SpecialCustomOperations, to define your own "language" to enable optional content in any text file.

It is a bit [badly](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/2090) documented feature, but I found great value from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422381/what-is-the-markdown-syntax-for-net-core-templating) to enable SpecialCustomOperations in markdown files.

In `template.config/template.json` it is needed to define

```
"SpecialCustomOperations": {
  "**/*.md": {
    "operations": [
      {
        "type": "conditional",
        "configuration": {
          "if": ["---#if"],
          "else": ["---#else"],
          "elseif": ["---#elseif", "---#elif"],
          "endif": ["---#endif"],
          "trim" : "true",
          "wholeLine": "true",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then following works

```
---#if (FooBar)
Foo bar
---#elif (BarBaz)
Bar baz
---#else
Baz qux
---#endif
```

In addition, I found that you can define similar operations for csproj files (that is basically xml). There you need to define (following an example in [this commnent](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/237#issuecomment-277070311))

```
"SpecialCustomOperations": {
"**/*.xaml": {
  "operations": [
    {
      "type": "conditional",
      "configuration": {
        "actionableIf": [ "<!--#if" ],
        "actionableElse": [ "#else", "<!--#else" ],
        "actionableElseif": [ "#elseif", "<!--#elseif" ],
        "endif": [ "#endif", "<!--#endif" ],
        "trim" : "true",
        "wholeLine": "true",
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
```

ps. list of filetypes where Special Operations are enabled by default can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/blob/5b5eb6278bd745149a57d0882d655b29d02c70f4/src/Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Orchestrator.RunnableProjects/SimpleConfigModel.cs#L389-L464). In other filetypes it is needed to define SpecialCustomOperations by hand.